# Show the Value of Radio button using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have three radio button. I want to get the values of the radio button when checked.

I am doing this

```
if ($('radio').is(':checked')){
        alert($('input[name=radioName]:checked').val());
    }
```

Here is my [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2LwAy/1/). Where am i doing wrong?

Comment: None are checked... I guess you want to bind onchange event: `$(':radio').on('change', function () {
    alert(this.value);
});`  http://jsfiddle.net/2LwAy/4/  Otherwise check one by default and then your question will make more sense

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one simple way

```
$('input:radio').click(function () {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')){
        alert($('input[type=radio]:checked').val());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

radio is not an element use the pseudo-class selector input:radio

https://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/

```
$('input:radio').change(function () {
    if ($('input:radio').is(':checked')){
    alert($('input[type=radio]:checked').val());
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Two more possible ways:

```
$('input[type=radio]').change(function(){
  if (this.checked) alert($(this).val());
  if ($(this).is(':checked'))  alert($(this).val());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2LwAy/9/

Answer (score 1):

here a one example you want :

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2LwAy/10/)

you should call `onchange` method .instead `is:checked`

**JQUERY**

```
$('#radio').on('change', function(){
    var radioval=$(this).val();
    $(this).next().text(radioval)
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" id="radio" name="group1" value="Milk"> <label>salam<label>
```